# cvs update when we have a conflict

Tags: linux, version-control, cvs

I am trying to update my local file with CVS UPDATE. I see the differences in CVS diff, but when doing cvs update I get nothing changed and I see M before my file name in the output. What is that and how to get my file updated?

Comment: Sorry, I know you probably won't like this, but can you change your version control system software? I mean the latest CVS release is from 2008.

Answer (score 2):

"cvs update" means that you download updates from the server to your computer. It sounds as if you are in fact trying to upload your updates from your computer to the server. In that case, you should use "cvs commit" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was the case that I updated my files using cvs update, but after that, I changed them locally. In that case CVS thought that I had the most up to date version of the file because it was, but since I changed the files after that, CVS was still seeing a difference between my files anf´d the files in the CVS repository.
The solution was to locally save my changes somewhere, checkout the most up to date version of the file, apply my changes and then do a commit after that.